# Pandas read_pickle() results in invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''ASF'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pickle

I have written some scripts which cluster data into data frames. Because my RAM size is too small to fit all the data at once I have to write it temporarily to disk by using the `df.to_pickle()` function. When I want to read the data again with the function `pd.read_pickle(path_to_file)`, at some point the script crashes with the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ASF'
```

Interesting is that this only happens on some systems,  on one of my pcs the script runs through with no error and all the results are correct. On another system, the script does not run through and throw the error as mentioned above. I checked if the data frames only contain numeric values and yes they are. I also used the same conda environment, as my first assumption was, that the error is may be dependent on a python or library version.

Also interesting is that the error appears on different systems on different `.pkl` files. But always the ValueError appears on the symbol `'ASF'`

I hope somebody has an idea where I can look for a solution, as it is important, that this script runs on all the systems.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try read pickle with 'pickle' module, usually pandas creates troubles in reading pickles.

Comment: @fuwiak i tried it and this did not solves the problem.  
# group_df.to_pickle(export_path)  
with open(export_path, mode='wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(group_df, f, -1)

and

# temp_df = pd.read_pickle(current_file_path)

with open(current_file_path, mode="rb") as f:
    temp_df = pickle.load(f, encoding='utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you try to read a string that was encoded with base64 using a different encoding like `pickle.loads(pickled_data.encode('latin1'))`. Try first decoding the base64-encoded data to get the original binary data.

```
pickled_data = base64.b64decode(pickled_data_b64)
data = pickle.loads(pickled_data)
```